# Erro em gráfico no R: "invalid color name"

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, data, dplyr, graphics

Estou trabalhando com o conjunto de dados `starwars`, do pacote `dplyr`. Meu objetivo é criar um gráfico com estes dados, onde a variável independente seja a altura dos personagens, e a dependente seja a sua massa corporal:

```
library(dplyr)
starwars
plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200))
```

O próximo passo seria diferenciar por cores as espécies das unidades amostrais, e é aqui que aparece uma mensagem de erro:

```
plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200), col = starwars$species)
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...): invalid color name 'Human'
```

O erro parece estar com a classe 'Human', mas o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que está usando um conjunto de dados do pacote `dplyr`, sugiro mergulhar de cabeça no `tidyverse`. Uma outra solução para criar esse gráfico, já com legenda, é usar a função `ggplot`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(starwars, aes(x = height, y = mass, colour = species)) +
  geom_point()
#> Warning: Removed 28 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

É possível excluir o outlier da visualização definindo os limites do eixo y com a função `scale_y_continous`:

```r
ggplot(starwars, aes(x = height, y = mass, colour = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 200))
#> Warning: Removed 29 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado, Marcus! Ainda acho o `tidyverse` um grande desafio, mas já consigo ver que vale muito a pena!

Comment: O investimento de tempo vale a pena. Ele pode parecer um pouco mais complicado no começo, mas é muito mais simples no longo prazo. [Eu tenho um workshop sobre o assunto](https://github.com/mnunes/workshopR/) que talvez te ajude.

Comment: Excelente material, Marcus, vai ajudar bastante! Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Porque `Human` tem a tipologia de Character.
Se você converter para `factor` você consegue fazer a identificação da característica no plot por cores.

```
tibble[,14] [87 × 14] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ name      : chr [1:87] "Luke Skywalker" "C-3PO" "R2-D2" "Darth Vader" ...
$ height    : int [1:87] 172 167 96 202 150 178 165 97 183 182 ...
$ mass      : num [1:87] 77 75 32 136 49 120 75 32 84 77 ...
$ hair_color: chr [1:87] "blond" NA NA "none" ...
$ skin_color: chr [1:87] "fair" "gold" "white, blue" "white" ...
$ eye_color : chr [1:87] "blue" "yellow" "red" "yellow" ...
$ birth_year: num [1:87] 19 112 33 41.9 19 52 47 NA 24 57 ...
$ sex       : chr [1:87] "male" "none" "none" "male" ...
$ gender    : chr [1:87] "masculine" "masculine" "masculine" "masculine" ...
$ homeworld : chr [1:87] "Tatooine" "Tatooine" "Naboo" "Tatooine" ...
$ species   : chr [1:87] "Human" "Droid" "Droid" ...
```

Assim:

```
plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200), 
    col = as.factor(starwars$species))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, fiz assim e funcionou! Só fiquei em dúvida sobre a legenda, pois quando inseri os comandos o R leu normalmente, mas ela não apareceu no gráfico: `plot(starwars$mass ~ starwars$height, ylim = c(0, 200),
col = as.factor(starwars$species), legend("bottomleft", legend = as.factor(starwars$species)))`